# update if multiple IF statements are true

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is how I image what I want.

```
SELECT dbo.AUDIT WHERE AUD_CloseDate IS NULL
IF AUD_CloseDate IS NULL
check if score is 100%
then update closed date
```

I need to select `AUD_CloseDate` where it is NULL, if it is null then check if `total` = 100% if that is true then update `AUD_CloseDate` column with today's date.

```
Total = (Scored / Total - NA) * 100
```

Not sure how to code this.?

Comment: Logic like this usually belongs in an application, read the data, do the checks and execute the update... is this a pure DB system?

Comment: check out the case statement in SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.AUDIT
SET AUD_CloseDate = GETDATE()
WHERE (AUD_CloseDate IS NULL) AND (Scored / Total - NA) *100 >= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work as intended :

```
UPDATE dbo.AUDIT
SET AUD_CloseDate = GETDATE()
WHERE AUD_CloseDate IS NULL AND (Scored / Total - NA) *100 >= 100
```

Answer (score 0):

You want an `update` statement, not a `select`. Simplified to remove redundancy:

```
update dbo.AUDIT set
AUD_CloseDate = getdate()
where AUD_CloseDate is null
and Scored / Total - NA = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a straight piece of SQL. I've used a parameter, but you could hardcode the value of the closed date, or use one of the current date functions.

```
UPDATE dbo.Audit SET AUD_CloseDate = @CloseDateValue 
WHERE AUD_CloseData IS NULL AND total = 100
```